If $f'(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$ prove that $f(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to 0$
Let $f:(0,\infty)$ be a differentiable function. I want to prove that if $f'(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$ this implies that $f(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to 0$ but can't wrap my head around how to proceed.
I was thinking I can probably use the formal limit definition and the fact that we know that $\forall M>0\; \exists N>0$ s.t. $x<N \implies f'(x) > M$. But I could not figure out how to relate this back to $f(x)$.

Consider $f(x)=\sqrt x$.

That makes total sense! To be sure, the other way around it would hold though, ie $f(x)\to \infty; \implies f'(x)\to -\infty$?

As $x \to 0$? I'm not so sure. If $f(x)=x + \sin x$, then $f'(1/x)$ seems like it might be a counterexample.
